# Ranking values in Excel columns

Tags: excel, vba

Given an Excel file with three columns (similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYqQF.jpg)): Group, Number and Rank.

Within the each group he must rank the values from smallest to greatest.  If the values match they get the same ranking.  So if a value is the largest, the rank would be 1.  If it was the second largest, the rank would be 2 and so on.

Then this process should restart for the second set of values.  How can this task be accomplished?  Maybe using arrays/bubble sort?—but I'm not sure that's the right approach.

Comment: I've just discovered the =Rank() feature of excel... which makes it pretty easy to sort one set of numbers for a given group... but how can I continue the process for every other set automatically?

Comment: take a look at this: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?343375-Rank-based-on-multiple-columns

Comment: I found some sort of answer... 
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$B$21=A2)*($B$2:$B$21>B2))+1

Problem is... it doesn't account for matches.  For matches it should rank them both as 2nd and 2nd, then the follow by the next order of rank.  So... the ranking could be something like 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5... something like that.  If that makes sense

Comment: Do you want a VBA solution or are worksheet solutions ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have the solution you are looking for - I had to do it in three columns though.

Assuming you have the group in column A and the score in volumn B; you are going to want to sort first by group and then by score.

Then you are going to want to go ahead and put the previously mentioned formula in column C2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$B$25=A2)*($B$2:$B$25>B2))+1
```

Then autofill that down.

Then you are going to want to put a counter in cell D2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2)=1,0,1)
```

Then autofill that down.

Then you are going to want to put this equation in cell E2:

```
=IF(C2<>C1,C2-SUMIF($A$2:A2,A2,$D$2:$D$25),C2)
```

Then autofill that down.

There might be a simpler/better way to do this - but this will definitely give you what you are looking for:

[image: Ranking Solution]

Comment: I want this to work so bad... for some reason my counter is showing zero all the way down.  Could you please show me what the formula would be in one of the cells that is giving you a one?  Maybe it isn't auto populating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem with one extra column:

In "C" column you have to have the inverse of the number frequency in the given group, using this formula (assuming the values go from row 2 to row 10):

```
=1/SUM(IF(($A$2:$A$10=A2)*($B$2:$B$10=B2);1;0))
```

Then in the next column (D) you can get the ranking you need by summing values in C:

```
=SUM(IF(($B$2:$B$10>B2)*($A$2:$A$10=A2);$C$2:$C$10;0))+1
```

Both formulas are array formulas (formulae?), you need to press Shift+Ctrl+Enter when entering them in Excel.

[image: Formatted as a table]

If you format your data as a table, you can use (in Excel 2010) the following formula:

```
=1/SUM(IF(([Group]=[@Group])*([Number]=[@Number]);1;0))
=SUM(IF(([Number]>[@Number])*([Group]=[@Group]);[Freq];0))+1
```

(Depending on your settings, you might have to replace the semicolons with commas.)

Comment: The first part doesn't work.  I a message saying that the formula contains an error.

Comment: Do you use decimal dot or comma? If it is the former, replace the semicolons ';' in my answer with commas ','. I double checked and the formula works.

Comment: I changed the semicolons to commas and it no longer gave me an error.  But it wouldn't provide the correct answer either.  I'll post a screenshot later of what I get.  = /

Comment: Please do. Maybe I did not understand your question correctly. Would you agree that the data on my screenshot are correct as per your definition?

Answer (score 0):

(Just noticed your comment but already written the following so may aswell upload it as it might be useful for future viewers of this question)

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$18=A2)*($B$2:$B$18>B2))+1` .

[image]

Comment: Umm... very very interesting.  When I use that formula... it doesn't match the records for ties.  It just continues sequentially.

Comment: strange - you can see from the screenshot what it does on my xl

Answer (score 0):

I did a custom sort with the first level of sort being the group column (smallest to largest) and the second level of sort being the value column (largest to smallest). Then in the rank column I used the formula

```
=IF(B2=B1,C1,COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2))
```

where A2 is the very first row. Then I dragged it all the way down.

This gives you the rank PLUS everything is visually sorted on the screen as when you're done.